# No error in var_dump($_FILES) during upload pictures but images not uploading

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

I have .php for upload images,now when I want to upload image multipart/form-data .php just reloaded without updating images. 
This is output of var_dump($_FILES)

```
 array(1) 
{ ["slika"]=> array(5) { 
["name"]=> string(8) "test.png" 
["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" 
["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpe46Qae" 
["error"]=> int(0) 
["size"]=> int(22970) } }
```

Is showing no error but image is not uploaded.
**EDIT**

```
This is hole php
form method="POST" action="" name="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Add your photo to the gallery</label><br>
<textarea name="opiss" placeholder="Description" style="margin: 2px; height: 150px; width: 238px;"></textarea><br>
<input name="slika" id="slika" type="file" style="width: 238px;" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="frienduh" name="frienduh" value="1"/> Check it.<br>
<span style='color: white;
padding-top: 6px;
font-size: 10px;
float: left;'>
    By clicking this your photo will become public!
</span><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="lodd" value="Add" class="button" name="dodaj" />

</form>




<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['dodaj'])) {



    $opis=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST['opiss']);


function died($error) { 
            $poruka = "We are sorry, but there was a problem with upload.\n\nErrors:\n$error\nPlease correct the error and try again.";
            ?>
            <script> alert(<?php echo json_encode($poruka); ?>); setTimeout(function() {window.history.go(-1)}, 500); </script>;  
            <?php

            die(); 
        }
    if($_FILES['slika']['size'] < 10485760){




                $opis = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['opiss']);
                if(strlen($opis)>301){
        died('You can enter up to 30 characters in the description field.');
    }
                $validExtensions = array('.jpg','.JPG','.jpeg','.JPEG','.png','.PNG','.gif','.GIF');
                $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['slika']['name'], '.');
                 if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {

                $newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
                            $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['slika']['tmp_name']);
                            // resizing to 200x200
                            $newImage3 = $manipulator->resample(800, 600);
                            // saving file to uploads folder
                            $manipulator->save('galerija/'.$newNamePrefix.$_FILES['slika']['name']);

                            if (isset($_POST['frienduh'])){
                                $frienduh=1;
                                }else{
                                $frienduh=0;
                            }


                    $upis=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO galerija VALUES(null,".$_SESSION['group_id'].",'".$opis."','".$newNamePrefix.$_FILES["slika"]["name"]."',0,".$frienduh.",0,0)") or die(mysqli_error($conn));



                            if (isset($_POST['frienduh'])){
                                $gal=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id_gal from galerija where putanja_slike='".$newNamePrefix.$_FILES["slika"]["name"]."'");
                                $gal_id=mysqli_fetch_array($gal,MYSQL_ASSOC);
                                $upis2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO main_board (id_gal,group_id,doing,content) values(".$gal_id['id_gal'].", ".$_SESSION['group_id'].", 'want to check', '<br><a href=\'/friendornot/photo/".$gal_id['id_gal']."\' title=\'".$opis."\' ><img style=\'max-width:350px;max-height:250px;\' src=\'/galerija/".$newNamePrefix.$_FILES["slika"]["name"]."\'/></a>' )") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                            }





                }else{
                    died('File type not allowed!');
                }


    }else{
        died('File size must be less than 5MB.');
    }

}
```

Just stop to work about a week or two. This is not my code previous developers left it. I can not fine answer why this upload stop to work.

**EDIT**

Is not problem with .php problem start after updating Debian 7 and php. This .php working on localhost and on other server. I did not fined solution for this if I find it i will post. Also folder galerija have all permision, and in php.ini evrithing is ok

```
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 12M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 12M
```

Comment: what you have tried for upload

Comment: I am trying to figure out why this is not working and work it before. I want to upload image-

Comment: try to replace the line `$manipulator->save('galerija/'.$newNamePrefix.$_FILES['slika']['name']);`with `try{$manipulator->save('galerija/'.$newNamePrefix.$_FILES['slika']['name']);} catch (Exception $ex) { echo "exception found";die() }` and check if it prints exception found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem start after updating of Debian Wheezy.

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor
>   version mismatch.

So this help to me maybe it will help to some one else.

> apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

And after installing image upload working again properly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to upload them manually.
Read more here:

http://php.net/manual/bg/function.move-uploaded-file.php